# Does Ubuntu provide extra fonts through a font package?

Tags: fonts

Is there a font-package the Ubuntu ships out that has more fonts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a bit extreme, is this attempt to install all fonts:

```
sudo apt-cache search ^fonts- | sed 's/^\(fonts-[^ ]*\).*$/\1/' | xargs sudo apt-get install
```

Comment: can make it a bit shorter with awk, `apt-cache search -n '^fonts-*' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo apt-get install` (this is probably like what I ended up doing, and also thinking it was a bit extreme)

Comment: BTW, Houston LInux Users Group ever Wednesday 6-9PM @ cPanel and then Cedar Creek @ 9pm

Comment: Cool, I'd like to check that out. I see the [cPanel](http://www.houstonlinux.org/support.html) one, but not Cedar Creek address.

Comment: We hit up Cedar Creek when we leave cPanel every wednesday. =) Not sure we advertise it, you're in the in-crowd now.

Comment: I [see](http://www.houstonlinux.org/social.html). Ha! Alright.

Answer (score 16):

Yes.

In a terminal...

```
apt-cache search font
```

will yield all results. Or...

```
apt-cache search font | grep ttf
```

will yield a list of TrueType fonts. You could save the output to a file to examine it:

```
apt-cache search font | grep ttf > ttf_font_packages
```

If you wanted 465 free TTF fonts in the ttf-aenigma package and the tuffy font after reading the output, then:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-aenigma fonts-tuffy
```

Aside from packages, you can create a directory for your own fonts.

```
cd
mkdir .fonts
```

Then, drop as many fonts as you like into that directory (~/.fonts).
You've also got some graphical software selection tools available if you do not like the terminal.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can have Windows TrueType fonts through Ubuntu Restricted Extras (Package that installs beyond fonts, flash, java and audio and video codecs) and TrueType Microsoft fonts Installer, to get them type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: `ubuntu-restricted-extras` will pull in **much** more stuff than just fonts.

Comment: Although anything there will harm his system and he will get his fonts... although it's always good to him to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option is to use the `Synaptic` or any other package manager and the section fonts from (universe) for example.