# Windows like softwares for Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu 14 LTS. I want the following Windows applications/functionality:

1. Times New Roman Font
2. Skype
3. File Explorer (like Windows Explorer)
4. One Note

that it for now. I would also want to know how I can access my old windows version. I had not removed it while installing ubuntu. But I can't access it anymore. Please help.

Comment: 1. http://askubuntu.com/a/234521/158442 2. http://askubuntu.com/q/488053/158442, 3. Already installed, press the Windows button and type "Files", or head to https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus/ 4. http://askubuntu.com/q/511629/158442.

Comment: @DiprajZagade This is really 5 questions in one, and will probably be closed soon as too broad. I recommend searching first, then ask detailed questions about whatever you still need help with. See [vittcor's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/51263) to [LibreOffice missing certain Microsoft fonts](https://askubuntu.com/q/34077) ([Installing Times New Roman font](https://askubuntu.com/q/210680) if you have trouble) and [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7498), for the 1st 2. Ubuntu comes with Nautilus, which is a file explorer. (It's unclear if you're looking for something else...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Answer (score 3):

1. For the fonts, you can try type this in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
   sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   ```
2. You can download Skype for linux directly from the official Skype website. Chose Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch) as your distribution. Once downloaded, go to your terminal and type:

   ```
   cd Downloads
   sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
   ```

   Note that I am assuming that the default download directory of your browser is ~/Download, which is default for Google-Chrome and Firefox. Also, the name of the .deb file can be different, so just type the correct name of the .deb file you just downloaded.
   Or just click here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/skype/
3. Depending on the ubuntu flavour you installed (Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu) you have a differnet default file manager. For Ubuntu, is `nautilus`. If you want to try a different one, there are plenty of options available. I like to use the `pcmanfm` which is really lightweight.
4. You can try `zim` as an alternative to one note

Answer (score 2):

1. For the font, install the Tweak tools so that you can set the fonts anyway you want them.

Open a Terminal window, and type in the following (also installing the TTF fonts):

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool font-freefont-ttf
```

Then after those are installed, press the Windows Key on the keyboard and in the search box type in `tweak` which will bring you to the tweak tools.  Then select the font you want in the fonts section.

2. For Skype, open a Terminal window and type in:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install skype
   ```
3. The file explorer is called Nautilus that is already installed.  You can get to it by pressing the Windows Key and in the search box type in `files`
4. There would be a lot of installation with an application called WINE to get OneNote working.  You can install PlayOnLinux

   ```
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```

   to install Microsoft Office.  However, WINE is always being improved on and there is possibilities that there could be failures running non-linux applications such as Microsoft Office.

As far as the Windows installation that you had, if you did not choose to have Ubuntu installed along side Windows, it may have formatted your drive losing your Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

Times New Roman can be replaced with Liberation Sans in libreoffice. As far as I know Times is proprietary. Skype already exists for ubuntu.  File explorer - there's a lot of them. I suggest Thunar or Dolphin. One Note. . . .haven't used it so no clue....

Will add links and maybe more info when not on mobile

Answer (score 1):

To get OneNote installed, you have to start with MSOffice.  Check either PlayOnLinux or WINE for the version of Office you have.

https://appdb.winehq.org/

https://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps.html

Comment: I would not recommend using wine  to run windows applications if there is any linux alternative. I my opinion, wine must be the last option =)